# C's Crypt() like function in Java

Tags: java, crypt

I have been reading some codes regarding encrypting a password in Java. Which seems a bit more computing intensive.

Is there a quick way to encrypt a string similar to C or Ruby?

For example, in Ruby:

```
'hello'.crypt('$6$salt') # => "$6$salt$ghQ6Rhatj/sug12c6v8Ao/bXUoyJ1O1SqdumufgGEO3b3NYPvm/dSWDKWfNm1VxFoFiy/cw9eRaY0xu4GDQSU/"
```

The method `String#crypt()` is from C, which is used in Linux to store hashed password in `/etc/shadow`:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/shadow | grep $USER
sourav:$6$Vx0wkV1M2PM43WOE$b2pYu.funKjk/snGSqiMTgh1e9dGQYDEKrjfuc2T/tP5qs7lXU56MjFvWd35rgzmYBXK33DrjQqnxTcPtcMXi/:18013:0:99999:7:::
```

Here's a small program...

Knowing that my system password is 55, in Ruby:

```
pass = IO.readlines('/etc/shadow').find { |x| x.start_with?(ENV['USER']) }
=> "sourav:$6$Vx0wkV1M2PM43WOE$b2pYu.funKjk/snGSqiMTgh1e9dGQYDEKrjfuc2T/tP5qs7lXU56MjFvWd35rgzmYBXK33DrjQqnxTcPtcMXi/:18013:0:99999:7:::\n"

h = ?$ + pass.split(?$)[1..2].join(?$)
=> "$6$Vx0wkV1M2PM43WOE"

s = pass.split(?$)[-1].split(?:)[0]
=> "b2pYu.funKjk/snGSqiMTgh1e9dGQYDEKrjfuc2T/tP5qs7lXU56MjFvWd35rgzmYBXK33DrjQqnxTcPtcMXi/"

hs = h + ?$ + s
=> "$6$Vx0wkV1M2PM43WOE$b2pYu.funKjk/snGSqiMTgh1e9dGQYDEKrjfuc2T/tP5qs7lXU56MjFvWd35rgzmYBXK33DrjQqnxTcPtcMXi/"

'55'.crypt(h) == hs
=> true
```

So the system can confirm my password is 55 and let me log in.

Is there a similar method in Java that can encrypt a string? Can I similarly run 'string.crypt("$6$salt")' and decrypt `/etc/shadow`'s account password if the account password is given?

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/Crypt.html

Comment: Note: `byte[] b = s.getBytes("UTF-8"); s = new String(b, "UTF-8");` or `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` i.o.` "UTF-8"`.

Comment: IDK why, but it says `error: cannot find symbol` I can't import `org.apache.commons.codec.digest.Crypt`  as well, which doesn't exist :(

Comment: @S.Goswami did you include the commons-codec jar in your buildpath?

Comment: Ok, so I have included that, and importing `import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.Crypt`, which seems to work fine. But there's the error of cannot find symbol while using the `crypt()` from example in the given link...

Comment: The compile option was `javac -cp sqlite-jdbc-3.27.2.1.jar:. -cp commons-codec-1.13/commons-codec-1.13.jar:. Register.java && java Register
`, the app is called Register

Comment: `javac -cp sqlite-jdbc-3.27.2.1.jar:commons-codec-1.13/commons-codec-1.13.jar:. ...`

Comment: Thanks a lot. The compilation was successful. But `System.out.println(Crypt.crypt("secret", "$1$xxxx")) ;` crashes for some reason :(

Comment: @S.Goswami ´ crashes for some reason´ that's not something we could help with

Comment: Oh got it, I was running `javac -cp sqlite-jdbc-3.27.2.1.jar:commons-codec-1.13/commons-codec-1.13.jar:. Register.java && java Register`. But it firxes the problem if I do: `javac -cp sqlite-jdbc-3.27.2.1.jar:commons-codec-1.13/commons-codec-1.13.jar:. Register.java && java -cp commons-codec-1.13/commons-codec-1.13.jar:. Register`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and decrypt /etc/shadow's account password if the account password is given

The *[crypt()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C))* function is not encryption, the function creates a salted password hash.

Hash is a one-way function and one of its primary features is that nobody should be able to recover password based from the (cryptographic) hash value.

> So the system can confirm my password is 55 and let me log in.

This is possible. Effectively you compute a new salted hash (using the same salt) and compare with the stored value.

> Is there a similar method in Java that can encrypt a string?

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.Crypt;

...

String hash = Crypt.crypt("password".getBytes());
System.out.println("salted hash: "+hash);
// salt is $X$some_bytes
String salt = hash.substring(0, hash.indexOf("$", 3));
System.out.println("salt: "+salt);
// validation:
String testString = Crypt.crypt("password", salt);
if(testString.equals(hash)) {
  System.out.println("Password match");
} else {
  System.out.println("Invalid password");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Java includes since 1.4 a package named [`javax.crypto`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/package-summary.html), which allows you to encrypt and decrypt data using a Cipher.

[TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_cryptography/index.htm) has a tutorial for this package. Here is a little Java snippet which first encrypts data, then decrypts it:

```
public class CipherSample {
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
  //Creating a Signature object
  Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");

  //Creating KeyPair generator object
  KeyPairGenerator keyPairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");

  //Initializing the key pair generator
  keyPairGen.initialize(2048);

  //Generating the pair of keys
  KeyPair pair = keyPairGen.generateKeyPair();      

  //Creating a Cipher object
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");

  //Initializing a Cipher object
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pair.getPublic());

  //Adding data to the cipher
  byte[] input = "Welcome to Tutorialspoint".getBytes();      
  cipher.update(input);

  //encrypting the data
  byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal();  
  System.out.println(new String(cipherText, "UTF8"));

  //Initializing the same cipher for decryption
  cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pair.getPrivate());

  //Decrypting the text
  byte[] decipheredText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
  System.out.println(new String(decipheredText));
  }
}
```

Not as straightforward, but still simple.

Comment: I'm not so sure this does the same thing the [`crypt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) function does

Comment: Even the asking person mixes hash and ciphertext, this answer is wrong an doesn't solve the question (it is even misleading)

Comment: I don't think this is Crypt(). Before asking the question, I read this on tutorialspoint, and there's a question on stackoverflow regarding cryptography in Java, but they are other algorithms...

Answer (score -2):

The crypt C library function uses DES as its encryption. You have to use the same algorithm if you want exactly the same result in Java.

In a nutshell:

```
    KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
    SecretKey desKey = keygenerator.generateKey();

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, desKey);

    byte[] encrypted = desCipher.doFinal(clearText.getBytes());
```

You can find a tutorial here: 
https://www.mkyong.com/java/jce-encryption-data-encryption-standard-des-tutorial/

Comment: Not really true, the first number `$6$` defines hash algorithm, mode 6 is sha-256